# неопределенная ссылка(undefined referance) 'readline' 'history' makefile

Tags: linux, c, makefile, readline

Не могу прокомпилировать в makefile,выдает ошибку undefined reference 'readline' , 'ad_history'.На рисунке---> в терминале выделил ошибку,слева input.h где вызываю библиотеку readline.h,справа makefile.За ранее благодарю.[image: ошибка]

Comment: Это все оттого, что Вы заголовочный файл зачем-то обзываете "библиотекой". Вот не библиотека он. Библиотека - это бинарный файл, который Вы должны скормить компоновщику в Вашем makefile. Где это у Вас? Если Вы используете системную библиотеку, то вероятно, поможет просто добавить к строке со сборкой `-lreadline`.

Comment: И? Снова "вызываю библиотеку readline.h"... `readline.h` - это **заголовочный файл**, а не "библиотека". Где у вас подключение самой библиотеки-то? Библиотеки  подключаются через параметр `-l`. Где ваш `-l`? Это не говоря уже о том, что у вас целая простыня ошибок отрапортована выше. В С обычно начинают исправлять ошибки с первой, а не с последней.

Comment: извиняюсь за ошибки =)Просто хочу скомпилировать все,а после уже эти варнинги исправить.Куда мне -lreadline надо вставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы в linux используете функции из сторониих библиотек (в данном случае readline) то необходимо в явном виде указывать ссылки на библиотеки, которые нужно прилинковать. В вашем случае необходимо в 9-ю строчку добавить `-lreadline`

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ,но можете подсказать куда именно вписать -lreadline?(я просто новичок)

Comment: прямо в конец 9-й строчки через пробел

Comment: Возможно, что в некоторых случаях надо добавлять `-L/path/to/lib` помимо собственно того, что вы написали.